# Bootstrap 3 Ignores custom.css on load

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this very strange problem.

I'm trying to code with **Bootstrap 3**. in the `<head>` I declare links for CSS to be used. Although the HTML completely ignores my third link.

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">        
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">      
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel"stylesheet">
</head>
```

As you can see, the third link refering to css/custom.css is there correctly. But on the website it's being completely ignored.

I have tried coding a simple button using

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Default</button>
```

And in custom.css I have the .btn class

```
.btn{
border-radius: 0px;
}
```

So the button's border should be straight not rounded like it is in bootstrap3. Problem is that my **custom.css** doesn't want to work and it's just completely ignored.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thank you.

Patryk.

Comment: Does using `!important` on your custom css make any difference?

Comment: Your declaration is rewrote or there is no declarations from your custom.css? You can use firebug to verify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add '=' after 'REL'.

Your code:

```
 <link href="css/custom.css" rel"stylesheet">
```

Should be:

```
 <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thank you so much Damian, I cannot believe I have missed that.

Answer (score 0):

If `custom.css` is correctly loaded than bootstrap code has a higher precedence, so you might want to use `button.btn.btn-primary{border-radius: 0px;}` or `.btn.btn-primary{border-radius: 0px!important;}`

As @Damian says it, the custom.css file is not loaded at all.

Comment: nah, bootstrap uses `.btn { border-radius:4px }` declaration

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Claudiu 

Although this still haven't solved my issue :( Code is being completely ignored.

Comment: Wrong declaration, see Damian answer